# Email Validation in JavaScript WITHOUT REGEX

Tags: javascript, validation

I am creating a form that involves the user input of an email. I want to create a validation for an email. I already know that you can use Regular Expression for this, but I don't want to use a regular expression. This is because, I want to identify to the user what is the problem with their input. Could someone give me this code? Thanks!

Comment: You can do this with regular expressions

Comment: I know that, but I purposely did NOT want to use them.

Comment: What do you mean by tell the user "what is the problem," do you mean where the error is in the email like, "missing a period" or "missing a @ sign"?

Comment: Yes, explaining the error.

Comment: Why not? Your reason for not using regex is that you want to show which part of the input is invalid? You'd have to use a lexer just for email strings, which is needlessly complicated since you can do the same thing with a regular expression

Comment: What makes you think regular expressions can't do what you want to do? That's like saying "we need to get this bed to my house from the other side of town but I don't want to use a truck. We'll need to airlift it via helicopter instead."

Comment: Why would you use JavaScript but not use RegEx?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's part of the HTML spec, but a lot of browsers have [an `email` input type](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_email)

`<input type="email">`

edit: apparently it's part of the HTML 5 spec.

Answer (score 0):

```
let ValidateEmailAddress = (email) => {
var countAt = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < email.length; i++) {
    if (email[i] == '@')
        countAt++;
    if (!CheckAllowedString(email[i])) {
        return false;
    }
}
if (countAt > 1 || countAt == 0 || IsAllowedCharacter(email.charAt(0)) 
== false)
    return false

var emailParts = email.split('@');
if (emailParts[0].length < 1 || emailParts[1] < 4 || 
emailParts[1].lastIndexOf(".") == -1) {
    return false
}

var length = emailParts[1].length;
var lastIndex = emailParts[1].lastIndexOf(".");
if (length - lastIndex <= 2) return false;
//check for -,.,_ double accurance
for (let i = 0; i < email.length; i++) {
    if (!IsAllowedCharacter(email[i]) && !IsAllowedCharacter(email[i + 
1])) return false;
}
for (let i = lastIndex + 1; i < length; i++) {
    if (!IsCharacterString(emailParts[1][i])) return false;
}
return true
}
let IsAllowedCharacter = (val) => {
if (typeof val === 'undefined') return true;
if (isCharacterNumeric(val) || IsCharacterString(val)) return true;
return false
}
let isCharacterNumeric = (character) => {
return $.isNumeric(character);
}
let IsCharacterString = (character) => {
var characterArray = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j", 
"k", "l", "m",
    "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"];
if (characterArray.indexOf(character.toLowerCase()) != -1) return true;
return false
}
let CheckAllowedString = (chr) => {
if (chr == '@') {
    return true
} else if (chr == '-') {
    return true
} else if (chr == '.') {
    return true
} else if (chr == '_') {
    return true
} else if (IsAllowedCharacter(chr)) {
    return true
} else {
    return false
}
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).